# See users who visited sharepoint site Search-UnifiedAuditLog

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Im trying to export a list of users who have visited the different sharepoint sites in my collection. I have tried and i can get it to work with internal users but not for external.

```
$startdate = "11/10/2017 8:00 AM"
$enddate = "11/10/2017 9:00 AM"
$userIDs = (import-csv C:\Junk\User.csv).Email
foreach ($userid in $userids) {
    $AuditlogMain = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startdate -EndDate $enddate -RecordType SharePoint -Operations PageViewed -UserIds $userID -ObjectIds "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/" -Formatted
    $AuditlogMain.UserIDs | Select-object -Unique | Out-File C:\junk\Main.csv -Append
}
```

I then get a list of unique users but i want to list all the external users also and i don't know how to simply change the mail from "@.com" to _.com#EXT#@.onmicrosoft.com

Or is there a more simple way to export the users that have visited a site?
If you look in `$AuditlogMain.AuditData` there are some more information i want but i don't know how to extract it. So if someone could help me with the external users or more preferably help me extract `ClientIP, ObjectId, UserId` from `$AuditlogMain.AuditData` that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts from the article provided:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

$extUsers = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "*#EXT#*" }

$extUsers | ForEach {
    $auditEventsForUser = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -EndDate $((Get-Date)) -StartDate $((Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -UserIds $_.UserPrincipalName

    Write-Host "Events for" $_.DisplayName "created at" $_.WhenCreated

    $auditEventsForUser | FT
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```

Here's an article that explains how to get audit info for external users:
https://www.sharepointappie.nl/using-powershell-to-get-audit-data-for-external-users/